# Django LOCALE_PATHS solution using Amazon EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, translation, freebsd, django-rosetta

We currently have two EC2 servers running apache servers with django wsgi on freebsd.  We use django rosetta for translations.  However, we have two servers with two different sets of files so if one of our translators translates in django rosetta, only one server will have the updated translations.  We need a solution to share the same LOCALE files across both systems.

We have tried setting up SSHFS and pointed LOCALE_PATHS in our settings.py to the mounted drive, however, django does not seem to recognize the mounted directory.  We modified all the permissions and everything we could think of to get django to see the mounted locale directory but with no success.

The question is, what other solutions are there for sharing the same set of translation files across two different servers on amazon EC2 web servers using freebsd and keeping them synced as changes occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to intelligently sync files across two machines. The steps to configure it are:

1. Install Unison on each machine
2. Configure SSH to be able to login between servers without password prompt
3. Edit Unison profile ~/.unison/default.prf on each server to match your needs

Below is an example of `default.prf`:

```
root = ssh://otherserver//home/user/folder/to/sync
root = /home/user/folder/to/sync

path = path/relative/to/root/dir1
path = path/relative/to/root/dir2

ignore = Path */.git/*
ignore = Path */logs/*

auto = true
batch = true
log = true
```

Now running `unison` command on either of your servers should sync files across both machines.

Comment: This works.  However, we decided to make our translators work on our development server and then just push the changes over as they come out.  Thanks